# \maketitle text before title

Tags: page-breaking, titles

I want my page to look something like this (using `\documentclass{article}`):

> text
>
> title
>
> text

but I can't get it right, it puts my title on the next page leaving my first text paragraph on separate page. What should I do?

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed (formatted) mockup of what you would like to achieve? It may narrow down the possible solutions.

Comment: I have some text at the beginning of my article
I defined 

\title{Naslov Prvog Zadatka}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle


and some text after this 

but when I compile it, title begins on a new page leaving text on first page..

Comment: This also works for moving my title lower on the title-page. \vspace*{...} before \maketitle actually moves the title now, instead of just inserting a blank page before the title :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`\maketitle` inserts a `\newpage` since the title is usually meant to be displayed at the top of the page. To avoid this, you can make `\newpage` a "no-op":

```
{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}
```

Placing it inside a group `{}` makes the change local. Here's a quick view on what the outcome of this modification is using a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Title}\author{Author}
\begin{document}
Some text

{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}

Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know how to reduce the space between the some text at the very top and the TITLE? Thanks

Comment: @FenceJumper: The default `\maketitle` macro (in the form used above) inserts a `2em` vertical skip before setting the title in a `center` environment. To see this, issue `\maketletter\show\@maketitle\makeatother` somewhere *before* calling `\maketitle`. You can either patch `\@maketitle` and remove this (with the help of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)), or just issue `\vspace{-2em}` before the call to `\maketitle`. See [this paste](http://pastebin.com/gKrZUD0r).