# Prevent page break when text exists before title in twocolumn enviornment

Tags: page-breaking, titles, two-column

I have an article using the two column enviornment but the title and abstract in a single column which works fine like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
    \maketitle
    \begin{onecolabstract}
    Here is my abstract...
\end{onecolabstract}]

\end{document}
```

I now need to add information BEFORE the title but it always causes a page break. I have tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86249/maketitle-text-before-title) and a couple more, but it didn't work. Unfortunately, I am quite new to TeX and couldn't find a solution that worked.

Comment: You can include the information above `\maketitle` *within* the `\twocolumn[...]` component.

Comment: Wow, amazing how I did not think of this /= Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents within `\twocolumn`'s optional argument is set inside a `\vbox`, which gobbles page breaks. So, even though `\maketitle` technically issues a page break you can insert the contents before but inside `\twocolumn`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example.
\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}
\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
  Something
  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
    {\lipsum*[1]}
  \end{abstract}]

\end{document}
```