# To create this Coversheet with Flexibility

Tags: titles

I try to create this cover sheet

[image]

I started to browse different variants of coversheets and think Warsaw's coversheet, [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/warsaw-university-of-technology-phd-thesis), is the closest. 
However, I do not the like the source code how it is accomplished.

My dummy-document but I started to think that I do not have the right tools now (not correct documentclass; there must be a better way to do this) where I created the align by minipages but the best way; probably same can be accomplished by fluhing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}
\title{THESIS FOR THE UNIVERSITY}
\author{} % no "immediate" warning wanted

% \begin{flushtop} % TODO do not know how to do this, since no command
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}\textbf{Lorem University} \\ \textbf{Department of Lorem} \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}Course: Lorem Lipsum \\ Curriculm: Lorem \end{minipage}    
% \end{flushtop}

\date{} % no timestamp
\maketitle

% not sure what to use here 
%  \raggedbottom vs flushbottom?
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65356/13173
\begin{flushbottom} % not working
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
Student: Lorem Ipsun \\ 
Year: 2015 \\ 
Day of birth: 1 \\ 
Nationality: USA
\end{minipage}
\end{flushbottom}

...
\end{document}
```

which gives two pages like

[image]

**How can accomplish such a coversheet?** 
I am also open to better i.e. more flexible ways to accomplish this. 
I may occur that I have to re-edit these coversheets fast to different formats so it would be nice to maintain flexibility.

Comment: Use the `titlepage` environment rather than `\maketitle`. The latter starts a new page.

Comment: What @cfr said and additionally [How to add a flyleaf code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: Or to put it in oter words, if the `titlepage` option is given (default for `report`), `maketitle` uses a `titlepage`-environment itself. The `titlepage-environment starts a new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it's probably better to use `titlepage`. However, you can keep things all on one page by using this answer to [\maketitle text before title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86255/24974) and `\vfill` to push things to the top/bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{THESIS FOR THE UNIVERSITY}
\author{} % no "immediate" warning wanted
\date{} % no timestamp

\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}\textbf{Lorem University} \\ \textbf{Department of Lorem}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}Course: Lorem Lipsum \\ Curriculm: Lorem \end{minipage}    
\par
\bigskip
{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}
\thispagestyle{empty} % must come after \maketitle
\vfill\flushright
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
Student: Lorem Ipsun \\ 
Year: 2015 \\ 
Day of birth: 1 \\ 
Nationality: USA
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I changed the widths of some of your `minipage`s in order to spread them out a bit.

Comment: Technically, this works, but man this is ugly LaTeX coding. ;-)

Comment: Agreed, but I wanted to show the OP's approach is doable if you prevent `\maketitle` from starting a new page.

To the OP: please don't accept this answer. A much better one is bound to come along :)

Comment: I hope so! +1 for courage and giving excellent start!