# How to make the book title within the page colored?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I color a page with tikzpicture and I want the book title can be placed at the center of the page colored. But when I write the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{\Huge C++ \\\qquad\textcolor{RedOrange}{Primer}}

\newlength\amount
\setlength{\amount}{0.33\paperheight}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[green] (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north east);
  \fill[yellow] ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-2\amount]current page.north east);
  \fill[red]([yshift=-2\amount]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-3\amount]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the book title begin a new page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\maketitle` automatically inserts a `\newpage`. To prevent this, we can do the same as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86255/143325, i.e. locally override the definition of `\newpage` so that it does nothing.

Note that the `tikzpicture` has to come *before* the `\maketitle` or it will overlay the text.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{\Huge C++ \\\qquad\textcolor{RedOrange}{Primer}}

\newlength\amount
\setlength{\amount}{0.33\paperheight}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[green] (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north east);
  \fill[yellow] ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-2\amount]current page.north east);
  \fill[red]([yshift=-2\amount]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-3\amount]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle} %<--------
\end{document}
```