# A4 format colored background

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm pretty new to Ti*k*Z and I'd like to make a page with a colored background with some circles on it.

I've already tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,latexsym,amssymb,amsthm,geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}  
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,backgrounds}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

%\pagecolor{blue}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=cyan!10}, show background rectangle]

        \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
            \fill[red!30!white]   (0:0) circle (0.5);
            \fill[green!30!white] (0:0) circle (0.25);
            \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:2.2) circle (0.3);
            \fill[purple!30!white]  (251:0) circle (0.3);
            \fill[brown!30!white]  (297:21) circle (0.3);
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I can't get a proper A4 format, so i tried to cheat by putting circles in the corners but even with it, the format isn't the good one. I've also tried with `\pagecolor` but it doesn't change the background color.

I don't know if it's the right place to post but I didn't find good solutions for now.

Comment: You are not looking at the paper, but the figure. Removing the `preview` lines will tell you that. Your figure is not in a4 size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in `preview` mode, i.e. you are not looking at the page itself, but the Ti*k*Z environment, which is not in the size of an `a4paper`.

The best way to customize the page in this way is, of course, draw directly on the page, not draw an independent `tikzpicture`. With option `remember picture,overlay`, the current of the page is recognized as a node named `current page`. Now you can use its anchors (`current page.north west` for example) to draw everything you want to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[cyan!10] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
\begin{scope}[shift={(-2,2)}]
    \fill[red!30!white]   (0:0) circle (0.5);
    \fill[green!30!white] (0:0) circle (0.25);
    \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:2.2) circle (0.3);
    \fill[purple!30!white]  (251:0) circle (0.3);
    \fill[brown!30!white]  (297:21) circle (0.3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have your `\maketitle` works in the page, you have to prevent page break on this command, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86255/156344). Go to that link to see why I put the whole story inside a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Foo bar baz}
\author{Titu}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[cyan!10] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
\begin{scope}[shift={(-2,2)}]
    \fill[red!30!white]   (0:0) circle (0.5);
    \fill[green!30!white] (0:0) circle (0.25);
    \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:2.2) circle (0.3);
    \fill[purple!30!white]  (251:0) circle (0.3);
    \fill[brown!30!white]  (297:21) circle (0.3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @titu Write everything _after_ the Ti*k*Z picture. Because the picture will `overlay` everything in that page, so everything written _before_ the picture will be hidden

Comment: Thanks you, do you also know how to write on it ? Like using \title() because, whenever i try to write on it, the text doesn't show.

Comment: @titu See my previous comment

Comment: Ok, it works with \textbf{} for example, but still not with \title{}, i should maybe use an other command ?

Comment: @titu I edited my answer