# Eliminate the extra page after use \includepdf

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, include, books

I have a question. I'm writing my thesis and I use a custom cover page using the \includepdf command, then I start the document, but I think this command adds an extra blank page after using it.. Check my code out:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \includepdf[pages=1]{portada_tesis.pdf} %the cover page, after it the blank page is added
    \maketitle %another filled page
    \thispagestyle{empty}
     The document text starts here...
\end{document}
```

Do you guys know why that happen and how to avoid the extra page ?

Comment: you are specifying both `openright` and `openany` which do you want? the first means chapters start on the right hand page, the second means they may be on either page.

Comment: Sorry, just a finger mistake... I'll fix it now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question. As far as I understand, you would like to have a »title page«, that displays »portada_tesis.pdf«. Then a second title page, produced by the command `\maketitle`?

If so, you need to say which title using `\title{whatever}`. To avoid an empty page, you can change `\maketitle`, using this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86255/4736 So I commented out `\maketitle` in your example and added a title and `{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\title{Title of Document}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \includepdf[pages=1]{portada_tesis.pdf} %the cover page, after it the blank page is added
{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}
%    \maketitle %another filled page
    \thispagestyle{empty}
     The document text starts here...
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanted to eliminate the "auto-added" blank page after the pdf document was showed. This worked really fine! Thanks a lot, body!!